# Unable to get a reactiveValues df to update based on user input in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am pretty new to shiny and am generating an app that features a VAR model based on user-inputted modification of the base data. Shiny is crashing on start-up when I don't have any data pre-loaded in my global environment (I've attempted hosting the data locally and externally and still get the same results).

I believe it has something to do with the way I'm specifying my reactive dataframe as I can run the code in simple R script, i.e. everything that is nested in `observeEvent(input$go,{`. Upon starting, I get the following error:

> Warning: Error in ts: 'ts' object must have one or more observations

If I have data in my global environment in R, it populates with a locally generated plot/data as soon as I hit the action button, which makes sense given it's nested under `observeEvent`. It does not update based on user inputs (particularly the forecasts).

If I do not have data in my global environment and I'm linking to my harddrive or a url, the screen goes gray as soon as I hit the action button and does not update at all.

I'm attempting to modify `combined_df`, a 190x7 dataframe, by applying four user-input scalar to four variables in `combined_df`. Then I'm attempting to impute past values of `temp` (one of the variables in `combined_df`) using previously estimated linear regression. The coefficients of a previously estimated relationship are stored in `coef`. The output should similarly be a 190x7 dataframe that I then use to construct time series and re-estimate a VAR model.

I think my problem has to do with specifying a function to a subset of a dataframe, but I am not sure how to proceed.

I've iuncluded my server code below:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    rv = reactiveValues(df_data = NULL) 

    observeEvent(input$go,{

        isolate({rv$df_data <- combine_df})

        rv$df_data$co2 <- combine_df$co2 * as.numeric(input$slider1)/100
        rv$df_data$sf6 <- combine_df$sf6 * as.numeric(input$slider2)/100
        rv$df_data$n2o <- combine_df$n2o * as.numeric(input$slider3)/100
        rv$df_data$ch4 <- combine_df$ch4 * as.numeric(input$slider4)/100
        rv$df_data$temp <- as.numeric(as.matrix(combine_df[3:6]) %*% as.matrix(coef$'fit$coefficients'[2:5]) - 97.05746141)})

        timeseries <- reactive({
            tsco2 <-ts(rv$df_data[, c('co2')], start=c(1997, 7),end=c(2012, 1),frequency = 12)
            tssf6 <-ts(rv$df_data[, c('sf6')], start=c(1997, 7),end=c(2012, 1),frequency = 12)
            tsn2o <-ts(rv$df_data[, c('n2o')], start=c(1997, 7),end=c(2012, 1),frequency = 12)
            tsch4 <-ts(rv$df_data[, c('ch4')], start=c(1997, 7),end=c(2012, 1),frequency = 12)
            trend <-ts(rv$df_data[, c('temp')], start=c(1997, 7),end=c(2012, 1),frequency = 12)
            multiplets <- ts_c(trend, tsch4, tsco2, tsn2o, tssf6)
            #multiplets <- window(multiplets, start=c(1997, 7), end=c(2012,1))
        })

        VARmodel <-  reactive ({VAR(timeseries(), p=3, type = "both")})

        fcast_for_plot <- reactive ({forecast(VARmodel(), h=50)})

        extractresults <- reactive({
            #fcastv1 <- forecast(VARmodel(), h=100)
            results <- fcast_for_plot()$model$varresult
            fcast_trend <- forecast(results$trend$model$y)
            fcasttrend <- as.data.frame(fcast_trend$mean)
        })

        repeatableplot <- reactive ({plot(fcast_for_plot(), xlab="Year")})


        output$varplot <- renderPlot({repeatableplot()})


        output$predtable <- renderTable({
            head(extractresults())})    
    }
```

edit: The ui code is below.

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
    pageWithSidebar(

        headerPanel("Greenhouse gas concentration and impact on Canadian Ground Temperature"),

        sidebarPanel(
            # Slider input for co2 change
            sliderInput("slider1", "Carbon dioxide (CO2) concentration percent change:",
                        min = 10, max = 200, value = 100),

            # Slider input for sf6 change
            sliderInput("slider2", "Sulfur hexafluoride (SF6) concentration percent change:",
                        min = 10, max = 200, value = 100),


            # Slider input for N2O change
            sliderInput("slider3", "Nitrous oxide (N2O) concentration percent change:",
                        min = 10, max = 200, value = 100),


            # Slider input for ch4 change
            sliderInput("slider4", "Methane (CH4) concentration percent change:",
                        min = 10, max = 200, value = 100),

            actionButton("go","Predict")
        ),

        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("varplot"),
            plotOutput("tempplot"),
            tableOutput("predtable")
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: hi, can you also add the ```ui``` part of your code?

Comment: @bretauv, thanks for your note. I added the ```ui``` in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The solution was:

1) Specify global functions for the time series

```
#specifying the function that will turn our data into a time series once it's adjusted, to be applied to rv$df_data (a)
timeseries <- function(x) {
    tsco2 <-ts(x[, c('co2')], start=c(1997, 7),end=c(2012, 1),frequency = 12)
    tssf6 <-ts(x[, c('sf6')], start=c(1997, 7),end=c(2012, 1),frequency = 12)
    tsn2o <-ts(x[, c('n2o')], start=c(1997, 7),end=c(2012, 1),frequency = 12)
    tsch4 <-ts(x[, c('ch4')], start=c(1997, 7),end=c(2012, 1),frequency = 12)
    temptrend <-ts(x[, c('temp')], start=c(1997, 7),end=c(2012, 1),frequency = 12)
    assign("temptrend",temptrend,envir=.GlobalEnv)  
    multiplets <- ts_c(temptrend, tsch4, tsco2, tsn2o, tssf6)
    multiplets <- window(multiplets, start=c(1997, 7), end=c(2012,1))
    assign("multiplets",multiplets,envir=.GlobalEnv)  
    VARobject <- VAR(multiplets, p=3, type = "both")
    assign("VARobject",VARobject,envir=.GlobalEnv)  
    fcast_for_plot <- forecast::forecast(VARobject, h=50)
    assign("fcast_for_plot",fcast_for_plot,envir=.GlobalEnv)
    return(fcast_for_plot)
}


timeseries2 <- function(x) {
    tsnewtemp <- ts(x[, c('temp')], start=c(1997,7), end=c(2012,1),frequency=12)
    newtempforecast <- predict(tsnewtemp)
    assign("newtempforecast",newtempforecast,envir=.GlobalEnv)  # put it in the global env
    return(newtempforecast)
}
```

2) Create a null data set for reactive values
3) Fill reactive values with dataframe
4) Create reactive variables based on user inputs
5) Recalculate columns of reactive variables once the user hits submit

See the final server code below, incorporating solution steps 2) - 5).

Also fun fact: I don't think the vars package accepts new datasets. If I run predict or forecast on our varest object, `VARobject`, it returns null vectors for forecasts.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    #specifying a reactive dataset that is currently empty, but will be populated by our dataframe
    rv = reactiveValues(df_data = NULL)
    rv$df_data = combine_df

    #Creating reactive variables based on user inputs, as percentages
    inp1 <- reactive ({(as.numeric(input$slider1))/100})
    inp2 <- reactive ({(as.numeric(input$slider2))/100})
    inp3 <- reactive ({(as.numeric(input$slider3))/100})
    inp4 <- reactive ({(as.numeric(input$slider4))/100})

    #Upon hitting predict, we recalculate the columns of our reactive data 
    observeEvent(input$go, {
        isolate({
            rv$df_data[,3] <- (combine_df[,3] * inp1())
            rv$df_data[,6] <- (combine_df[,6] * inp2())
            rv$df_data[,4] <- (combine_df[,4] * inp3())
            rv$df_data[,5] <- (combine_df[,5] * inp4())
            rv$df_data[,2] <- (as.numeric(as.matrix(rv$df_data[3:6]) %*% as.matrix(coef$'fit.coefficients'[2:5]) - 97.05746141))
            assign("rv$df_data",rv$df_data,envir=.GlobalEnv)

        })
    })    


        a <- reactive ({timeseries(rv$df_data)})
        b <- reactive ({timeseries2(rv$df_data)})

        repeatableplot <- reactive ({plot(a(), main="Initial forecast and updated values", xlab="Year")})
        repeatableplot2 <- reactive ({plot(b(), main="Estimates of Temperature Updated Trend", xlab="Year")})
        repeatabletable <- reactive ({b()}) 

        output$varplot <- renderPlot({repeatableplot()})
        output$tempplot <- renderPlot({repeatableplot2()})
        output$predtable <- renderTable({repeatabletable()})  

    }
```